# loading data in uitable view

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i am developing a simple view based application which contains two buttons and a table view which parses the rss feed.my view has got two buttons at the top and i am adding uitableview from interface builder...ive added delegate and data source of the table view as file s owner....the parsing process is done in a seperate file and i am using delgation to receive the parsed data....every thing works fine except for
[self.tableView reloadData] 
which gives an error and if i am to comment this i m not getting the data to be loaded in the table view.......this loading of parsed data works fine if im to create a navigation based application.but if i am to create a view based application and add table view progrmatically from interface builder creates problem ,cud u guys help me out....below is the code..

```
@implementation FirstViewController

@synthesize items;

@synthesize items2;

- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    [self loadData];


}

-(void)loadData

{

if (items==nil) 
    {

Parser1 *rssparser=[[Parser1 alloc]init];   

rssparser.delegate=self;

[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=YES;

[activityIndicator startAnimating];

[rssparser startRssFeed:@"http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne"];


        [rssparser release];
    }else
    {
        //[self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
-(void)receiveFeeds:(NSArray *)theItems
{   
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=NO;

[activityIndicator stopAnimating];

items=theItems;

NSLog(@"ha ha ha items:%@",items);
    //[self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {


    return [items count];

}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 

reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

 }

    cell.textLabel.text=[[items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"title"];
    cell.textLabel.text=@"hello";

cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

   return cell;
}
```

Comment: what is tableViewController in your code? is it a viewController object? is it contains a property called tableView?

Comment: no its [self.tableView reloadData]....i dont know whats its use....but if im to comment[self.tableView reloadData] i m not getting loaded with the data stored in items array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running your app with NSZombieEnabled = YES in the environment settings. Maybe you have a memory allocation issue somewhere.

My educated guess is that:
items=theItems;

you do not retain the items array and it gets autoreleased before you use it