# Parse, UITableView and reloaddata

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform

I'm sitting on this almost 4 days and I can't find the problem (already searched google a lot and tried everything but nothing helped). I have this table view I created on my storyboard. Everything is connect BUT when I run my code:

First all the tableView method runs but since array still nil nothing happened. Then after my array got all the data and code says [tableView1 reloadData]; nothing happened and I'm not getting to the tableView methods... (I tried to locate the reloadData in many places in my code and nothing worked).

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView1.dataSource=self;
    self.tableView1.delegate=self;
    self.tripNamesList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [self GetTripsList];
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Trips"];
    NSString *userID = user.objectId;
    [query whereKey:@"User_Created_ID" equalTo:userID];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d trips.", objects.count);
            [self.tripNamesList addObjectsFromArray:objects];
            NSLog(@"%@", tripNamesList);
            for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                NSLog(@"%@", object.objectId);
                [self.tripNamesList addObject:object ];
            }   
            [tableView1 reloadData];
        }
        else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.tripNamesList count];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"Calling 1222rrgdfghgfhdgfdfgfdgdfgd on %@", tableView);

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TripCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
    }

    PFObject *obj2 = [self.tripNamesList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Trips"];
    PFObject *searchedItems = [query getObjectWithId:obj2.objectId];
    NSString *tempTripName = [searchedItems objectForKey:@"Trip_Name"];

    cell.textLabel.text = tempTripName;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    [self.tableView1 reloadData];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Comment: Reload data in cellForRowAtIndex.  That method is triggered by reload data and is called for every visible row.  That's a disaster.  Comment out all the parse stuff, delete the reload data, init your array to an array of strings, and let us know what happens.

Comment: already done that and everything worked

Comment: Okay.  Step 2:  prove you can initialize the array of strings with parse.  (But that reload data in cellForRowAtIndexPath _must_ be deleted).

Comment: yes array is initialized...I can see it gets all the object

Comment: Any particular reason you are not using PFQueryTableViewController?

Comment: possible duplicate of [loading data in uitable view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699985/loading-data-in-uitable-view)

Answer (score 0):

Try running the reloadData from the main thread:

```
 [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d trips.", objects.count);
                [self.tripNamesList addObjectsFromArray:objects];
                NSLog(@"%@", tripNamesList);
                for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                    NSLog(@"%@", object.objectId);
                    [self.tripNamesList addObject:object ];
                }   

                 dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        [self.tableView1 reloadData];     
                  });                
            }
            else {
                // Log details of the failure
                NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            }
        }];
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to call `[tableView reloadData]` everywhere. Once this method is called, the tableview's delegates will be called in order like `numberOfRowsInSection` and based on the number of rows, that much time `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will be called. So in your case, you have put `reloadData` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and it will create an infinte loop, I guess.

Also, since you are filling self.tripNamesList in background thread, you can call reloadData in main thread as like below

```
for (PFObject *object in objects) {
            NSLog(@"%@", object.objectId);
            [self.tripNamesList addObject:object ];
        }  
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(refreshTableData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Yes, for this you need to have a method like this in your .m

```
- (void) refreshTableData{
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I put breakpoints inside the methods but again - after performSelectorOnMainThread this is still not executing numberOfSectionsInTableView at all...

Comment: reload data now looks like suppose to run on time now but now the problem its not entering numberOfSectionsInTableView...

Comment: You mean, none of ur tableview delegate methods getting called?

Answer (score 0):

Try to move your code from viewdidload to viewdidlayout, viewwillappear or viewdidapear, your table might not be initialised yet at that point.